# Table is shown in pdf only one char by line

Tags: mpdf

I want to generate a pdf document from some html code. The html comes out of a sql database. The sql content is not shown line by line in the pdf document, but rather only one char in a line.

On my webpage, the html code shows a html table in the desired manner, e.g. first column  containing the sql database column name, second column the corresponding values. As an example the first line should be "ID 158". In the pdf document, I get only one char in each line. With the preceeding example, I get in the pdf document
"I
 D
 1
 5
 8".

Here's my code to generate the pdf:

```
// Require composer autoload
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
// Create an instance of the class:
try{
  $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['debug' => true]);

// $sub[1] originally comes from the sql database and contains about 70 table rows
$sub[1] = '<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%"class="print_table one_item"><tr><th ALIGN="LEFT" width="140">ID</th><td ALIGN="LEFT">158</td></tr><tr><th ALIGN="LEFT" width="140">Version Eingabeformular</th><td ALIGN="LEFT">2</td></tr></table>';
$mpdf->WriteHTML('Hello World');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($sub[1]);
// Output a PDF file directly to the browser
$mpdf->Output();
```

The pdf document should look similar to the following picture:
[Desired look of pdf document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZsUG.png)

The pdf document looks like
[Real look of pdf document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZDGr.png)

Does anybody have a hint for me to get a proper solution?
Regards, Thorsten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed it. Problem was a missing blank between the width and the class attribute of my table definition. If I add the blank, it seems to work fine...

```
width="100%"**missing blank** class="print_table one_item">
```